# Zybook - paint challenge python

Tags: python, paint

Scenario: Finish the program to compute how many gallons of paint are needed to cover the given square feet of walls. Assume 1 gallon can cover 350.0 square feet. So gallons = the square feet divided by 350.0. If the input is 250.0, the output should be:
0.714285714286
____________________________________-

```
gallons_paint = 0.0

wall_area = float(input())

# Assign gallons_paint below

''' Your solution goes here '''

print(gallons_paint)
```

---

I've been trying different combinations and I can't figure out how to get the float right.
Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: you're just asking others to solve these challenges for you...

Comment: Nah, that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `wall_area` is a floating point number, it's simple:

`gallons_paint = wall_area / 350`

Comment: Appreciate it! I wasn't thinking about it being so simple lol.

Comment: The expression in your question literally gives you the answer. It just tells you to divide the area by 350.0.